# how can i retrive or get Yahoo Weather API from JSON object channel -> item -> forecast -> {day1 } {day2} {day3 } {day4} {day5 }

Tags: java, android, json, yahoo-api

I tried to reach to the forecast data but failed, `NullPointerException` and sometimes crash. because i fail to reach or retrieve data from item `-> forecast -> {data}`.

At Item class:

```
    condition = new Condition();
    condition.jsonPopulate("condition");
```

At Condition Class :

```
    void jsonPopulate(data){
        temp = data.optString("temp");
    }
```

I got data at condition class successfully,

But why i cant do the same for forecast since forecast and condition are siblings.

Since forecast has array object so I tried like below retrieve data :

**Context Item class sending object of forecast** 
Code of Item class like below.

```
    forecast= new Condition();
    forecast.jsonPopulate("forecast");
```

**Context Forecast Class when retrive data from forecast object**
Code of forecast class like below.

```
    private String  day;
    private String high;
    private String low;
    ArrayList<ForecastDetails>fdetails;

    public void jsonPopulate(data){
    for(i=0; i<data.length(); i++){
            day = data.optString("day");
            high = data.optString("high");
            low = data.optString("low");

            fdetails.add(day);
            fdetails.add(high);
            fdetails.add(low);
        }

    }
```

and try to keep in a `ArrayList<ForecastDetails>;`
but failed, anyone has can suggest me about how to retrieve forecast data from item object of Yahoo weather.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject d = new JSONObject(data);
    for(i=0; i<d.length(); i++)
    {
        day = d.getString("day");
            high = d.getString("high");
            low = d.getString("low");

            fdetails.add(day);
            fdetails.add(high);
            fdetails.add(low);
    }
```

Comment: You mean I should use getString("day") instead of optString("day");

Comment: you can use optString also no Issue..!!! The difference is optString returns the empty string (" ") if the key you specify doesn't exist and getString on the other hand throws a JSONException if the key is not present in the JSON

Comment: you said JSONObject d = new JSONObject(data);

I did like this 
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(s);
JSONObject queryResult = data.optJSONObject("query");

query->channel->item->forecast->{},{},{},{},{};

i access till forecast, but not its data inside curly of forecast i tried like above you mention but not getting data.